# Changed path of /tmp folder is not reflected

Tags: linux, apache, unix

I changed path of temporary folder from /tmp to a new path. I made these changes in /etc/environment file. I added following lines.

TEMP="path to new folder"
TMPDIR="path to new folder"

But still /tmp folder is being used as temporary folder.

The reason I want to change the path is because size of /tmp volume is very less.

Any reason why changes wouldn't be reflected? Do I need to reboot the server?

Comment: please tell us what context is is not working. Inside an applicatoin (which ones (just a few examples!)) AND / OR from the command-line. What happens when you start a new window and the do `echo "TEMP=$TEMP"; echo "TMPDIR=$TMPDIR"`. **Edit your question to include this info**. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put a symlink to the new directory if possible as so many apps and system processes are likely still looking for it.

```
ln -s /path/to/new/tmp /tmp
```